# Does the word erection have a neutral tone with its non-sexual definition?

Tags: word-choice, copywriting

I want to write:

> Our higher-profile projects include the delivery and *erection* of large exhibition stands for --company name-- at --redacted-- Championship;

<sup>The emphasis is only to highlight the problem word here and is not present in the actual copy.</sup>

I can't help worrying that erection introduces something unnecessary.

I could replace it with "delivering and assembling" instead, but erection is technically correct and a more precise word.

I need an outside opinion on whether erection introduces any possible effect, even a momentary confusion or lapse of focus, that I wouldn't want for formal commercial copy?

Sorry if this is a silly question or off topic.

Comment: This question *might* get a better answer at [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) since that site specializes in such matters. If you want to migrate it, click the flag link at the bottom of your post and flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to migrated to English Language and Usage. It **is** on topic here, so it does not *have* to be migrated.

Comment: @PaulAClayton I figured this is more of a writing topic than a definition type question. If it doesn't get any answers I wouldn't mind migrating it to see, but I am hoping someone can weigh in here. I don't think ELU take kindly to questions that invite opinions that can't be explicitly quantified.

Comment: When you say "erection" is more correct and precise - what are you basing this on? Because whatever's standard in the field is probably the best way to go. If everybody says "erection", it won't, ummm, stand out.

Comment: I thought connotation was part of what ELU covered, but I am not familiar with ELU. Here at Writers one might (ideally) get a more general answer (like [what's answer](http://writers.stackexchange.com/a/14535)) dealing with the broader issue in writing. Such an answer would be useful for addressing other similar questions of usage. At ELU (I suspect) one would get a more linguistically interesting answer (which might tend to be more detailed on usage of the specific word, i.e., a "better" answer) which would improve your understanding of linguistics and English in particular.

Comment: @Standback 'To erect' a stand is far more explicitly descriptive than 'to assemble' a stand. Also, I feel assemble is a much weaker version. I assemble a Kinder Egg toy but I don't erect it. (at)Paul posting on ELU is like asking for an argument in my experience. It would be interesting to see their answers, but I don't want to argue.

Comment: I would see the double entendre. As an editor, I would change it to something else. *Assemble* or *install,* probably.

Comment: @LaurenIpsum thanks for weighing in, I'm back in two minds again. *Install* is an option I hadn't thought of and I'm leaning towards it. Do you think install implies 'piece together with tools' sufficiently?

Comment: @user "Install" to me means "Start with all the pieces, put it together, test to make sure it does what it's supposed to do, and clean up the site afterwards." Installing an exhibition would involve putting it into place, and if that required tools, that would seem to be understood.

Comment: @user Did anyone even try to find how this business sector talks about what they do? Look here: https://www.google.com/search?q=erection+exhibition+stands

Comment: @LaurenIpsum I'm going to go with install as it eliminates all doubts in my mind. Can you post it as an answer please?

Comment: @what I appreciate your help, and had I not been able to find an alternative, I would've gone ahead with this, but install has all the same benefits without a shadow of sexual connotation. Analysing its keyword potential was going to be my next port of call but I've found a better option. On that note, those search results weren't so relevant to what I'm aiming for, so that's further reason to avoid using it. Again, thank you.

Comment: I'm sure you'll always have the immature giggle at the comment, but in context the use of the word is valid and non-sexual.   Shame on them for corrupting the thing, not on you for using the word in an unambiguously non-sexual manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would see the double entendre. As an editor, I would change it to something else. *Assemble* or *install*, probably.

"Install" to me means "Start with all the pieces, put it together, test to make sure it does what it's supposed to do, and clean up the site afterwards." Installing an exhibition would involve putting it into place, and if that required tools, that would seem to be understood.

Comment: Well, you don't *install* a statue or *assemble* a fence, you erect them. Trying to avoid words with a double meaning at the cost of imprecise expression or cumbersome paraphrase is just silly. A cock is a bird, a prick is what happens when you aren't careful with your needlework, Dick is the name of my dad, and balls are what people kick around on a soccer field. And in another context those words mean something else. No one has a problem with the double meaning of words like bank, why do you assume they get confused when words have a sexual connotation?

Answer (score 3):

In the given context the word "erection" does not have any sexual connotations for me. Outside of your question, I would not have thought of erect penises at all.

If you feel you must avoid this word, use verbs: "We deliver and erect stands." Or: "The delivery and erecting of stands."

Many sexual slang words have non-sexual base meanings and are commonly used in this meaning, despite the fact that sometimes they induces laughter in children of a certain age. You wouldn't avoid telling these people to "grab their balls" either, would you?

[image: Image showing a group of young people training with red balls]

"Now grab your spheres firmly and bend to the side!"

Comment: So I should just be mature and expect the readers to do the same? :)

Comment: I would go farther than that. At the point when the word "erection" appears in your text, your readers (or listeners) have been primed (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_%28psychology%29) by the context of your speech to make the non-sexual meaning of the word salient (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salience_%28neuroscience%29), so that the sexual meaning will not even come to their minds, unless other information (e.g. the porn movie they have just viewed on their smartphone or your sexy dress) prompts them otherwise.

Comment: Is three short paragraphs into the page enough priming though? I need to read those resources and will do shortly, thank you.

Comment: Also, "erection" is certainly the appropriate technical term in the building industry, and your target audience will expect a certain meaning when they pick up your information. Someone on the lookout for your services will expect to read about the construction of buildings and not have an image of a penis in his mind. After all, as I understand your question, you are not writing for an unprepared audience.

Comment: I think you have primed yourself to be unable to not think of male anatomy at the moment ;-) Why don't you write your text and give it to a friend to read and then ask them if they thought of boners when they read it. And please post the results! :-P

Comment: I was ready to go ahead with it and then another user who I'm familiar with on another site gave an opinion that sided with my original doubts, and now I'm unsure about it again.

Comment: Yes, I would avoid telling people to "grab your balls". I'd choose "Pick up a ball", or "hold the ball firmly". In a class of men, at least some would laugh at the phrasing "grab your balls".

Comment: @WilliamHertling Fair enough. I (who answered this question a long time ago) am not a native speaker of English, so your correction is strongly appreciated. But it doesn't change the essence of my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are other word choices that avoid the problem, so why not use them? Construct, assemble, build, put up, fabricate.

If you spot the problem, then at least some others will at well. If you want to avoid that, pick a different word.